# How to efficiently "make" with Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, makefile

What I am trying to do seems a very basic stuff, but I can't find anything about it. I am working on a project built as usual:

```
project
|-- bin
|-- inc
`-- src
```

I would like to make my project using the make command included in Vim. But each time I have to specify `:make -C ../`. I would prefer, if there is not Makefile file in the current directory, go in the parent directory. I already do that with

```
set tags+=./tags;/
```

in my `.vimrc`.

Furthermore, the make is by default ugly. Are there options to add color to make, and allow a direct access to the errors (as in Emacs).

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution of rampion is a first step, but computed on vim load. When I load a multi tab session, the path can be inconsistent from one tab to another.

Here my solution (+ extra with tabnew).

```
fun! SetMkfile()
  let filemk = "Makefile"
  let pathmk = "./"
  let depth = 1
  while depth < 4
    if filereadable(pathmk . filemk)
      return pathmk
    endif
    let depth += 1
    let pathmk = "../" . pathmk
  endwhile
  return "."
endf

command! -nargs=* Make tabnew | let $mkpath = SetMkfile() | make <args> -C $mkpath | cwindow 10
```

Answer (score 17):

Slight modification of [what Adam said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/how-to-efficiently-make-with-vim/731393#729291):

```
 :set makeprg=[[\ -f\ Makefile\ ]]\ &&\ make\ \\\|\\\|\ make\ -C\ ..
```

Unescaped, this is

```
 [[ -f Makefile ]] && make || make -C ..
```

which means, pseudo code style

```
 if file-exists(Makefile) 
 then make
 else make -C ..
```

This only goes one directory up.  If you'd like a more general solution that will go
as many directories up as necessary, you'll need to be able to search ancestor directories until a Makefile is found, and I'm not sure how to do that simply from the command line.  But writing a script (in whatever language you prefer) and then calling it from your makeprg shouldn't be hard.

Comment: One can use a `let` clause to avoid such an extensive escaping: `:let &makeprg = '[[ -f Makefile ]] && make || make -C ..'`.

Comment: `[[ a ]] && b || c` is not exactly the same as `if a then b else c`. If `a` is true and `b` returns with a non-zero exit code, then `c` will be executed as well.

Comment: reiner-torenbeek: good point. How about `[[ a ]] && (b ; true) || c`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second question, you can navigate through the errors using the [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html) functionality in VIM. Quickfix stores the errors in a buffer and allows you to navigate forward/backwards through them.

You may have to define the error regexp to allow VIM to identify these from Make's output, but I seem to remember that it works out-of-the-box rather well (I've had to modify how it works for Java Ant builds - obviously doesn't apply here)

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest solution is to have a Makefile in your src directory, which is the way that many, many projects are set up regardless of editor/IDE. You can still have a top-level Makefile that calls `make -C src`, with the rules for building in src located in src where they belong.

Comment: I don't know why projects don't opt for a top-level Makefile whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach can be used if you have a single makefile on project root directory:

```
project
|-- bin
|-- inc
|-- src
| Makefile
```

With your project path in variable like `b:projectDir` it is possible to use an "autocommand" to change to that directory before start executing `:make`or `:lmake`:

```
augroup changeMakeDir
    au!
    autocmd QuickfixCmdPre *make
                \ if exists("b:projectDir") &&
                                    \ b:projectDir != expand("%:p:h") |
                    \ exe 'cd ' . b:projectDir |
                \ endif
augroup END
```

---

[Projectroot plugin](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-projectroot) can be used to set `b:projectDir`; it also provides the commands to change the current directory to the project root directory:

```
augroup changeMakeDir
    au!
    autocmd QuickfixCmdPre make ProjectRootCD
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

set makecmd="make -C .." in your .vimrc

Comment: I would prefer, if there is not Makefile file in the current directory, go in the parent directory. If Makefile exists, use it.

Comment: that's not so easy.  set your makecmd to be a script that tests that condition... it's not all that hard to do :)

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking. I don't know how to test if a file exists or not in the vimrc