# Vim save then make automatically?

Tags: vim

I want to call a command when I save the file.
I am calling it by `:make` manually now, but I wish it could be called when I execute `:w` and `:wq`.

I also want enable this feature in any subfolder that doesn't contain a Makefile but its parents contains one. Just like this topic said, but it doesn't works for me:

[How to efficiently "make" with Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/how-to-efficiently-make-with-vim)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/how-to-efficiently-make-with-vim

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> make
```

Comment: the "make" is as a shell command or a vim command? could it be an vim function?

Comment: `:make` is a vim command that runs the `make` shell command and reads its output to make sure everything worked.

Comment: If you want to save sometimes without autocommand, prepend with `noautocmd`. e.g.: `noautocmd wq`. You can map a key to save and close, such as F4 by editing vimrc with `vim ~/.vimrc`, then add line: `map <F4> :noautocmd wq <CR>`. I also added an F3 key to save and make by adding to vimrc: `map <F3> :w <CR>`

Answer (score 5):

```
au BufWritePost        *.c
            \ make
```

Comment: @Pablo - Actually, it goes in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think I should share this. Here goes my recipe, works pretty well:

```
    let autocompiled_filetypes = [
        \ 'php' ] " 'ft2', 'ft3', 'etc'
    au BufWritePost * call feedkeys("\<Esc>")
        \ | if index(autocompiled_filetypes, &ft) >= 0 |
        \ | silent! make % | cw | call feedkeys("\<Enter>")
        \ | endif
```