# Set vimrc makeprg to custom script if no Makefile

Tags: vim, makefile

I want the `:make` command to execute normally if there is a `Makefile` present. Otherwise I want it to execute a custom script, say, called `compile`. If neither file is present, I'd like it to fail gracefully (ideally not leave the editing screen).

I'm aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/), which presents a bash expression I was able to adapt to suit my needs. EXCEPT I sometimes need to run a shell other than bash. Is there a shell-independent way to do this?

Comment: The mentioned bash expression can look like this for gnuplot scripts. In .vim/after/ftplugin/gnuplot.vim: ```setlocal makeprg=([[\ -f\ Makefile\ ]]\ &&\ (make\ $*;\ true)\\\|\\\|\ gnuplot\ -persist\ %\ $*)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeprg` can be set to the name of any executable. Make a shell script that runs `make` if there is a Makefile, otherwise run `compile`, or else return.

Comment: The goal is to do it in the vimrc, so I don't have to make such a file for every project.

Comment: In that case, can you just change the value of the `shell` option in concert with the value of the `makeprg` option?

Comment: Ah, well, I was trying to avoid that. But sure enough `:set shell=/bin/bash` did the trick, so I'll go with it.