# Vim Makefile in parent directory

Tags: vim, makefile

For projects that have a Makefile in the parent directory of sourcefiles, in vim I have my
makeprg variable set as such:

```
:set makeprg=[[\ -f\ Makefile\ ]]\ &&\ make\ \\|\\|\ make\ -C\ ..
```

as suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/how-to-efficiently-make-with-vim)

This substiution works great for the Makefile in the parent directory, but breaks when the Makefile is in the current directory.

vim makes and infinite loop of :make commands. I've played around with the command to run if it doesn't find the Makefile, and I've determined that after running make, vim runs the fail case of the ternary anyway (as an editor command).

Thus the new call to :make expands to have another :make infinitely.

How can I prevent vim from trying to execute this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fail case of the ternary is run because, apparently, the invocation of `make` in the current directory returns with an error. You can prevent this flaw by setting `makeprg` as follows:

```
:let &makeprg = 'if [ -f Makefile ]; then make; else make -C ..; fi'
```

Using the `let` construct avoids the necessity of the escape signs. This was suggested in that same thread you refer to, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729249/how-to-efficiently-make-with-vim#comment9525693_731393).

Or you can fix the `make` problem in your current directory so that it does not return with an error code...

Comment: If I may do a feature request for this oneliner... Is it possible to hide the fact that make entered that directory? With this solution you'll have to hit enter twice.

Comment: Never mind, that can be handled by e.g. setting `set cmdheight=2`.

Comment: If you run `:make` with arguments, need to specify their location (`$*`) in the makeprg line. I also added `-C` to run make in the direcrory/sub-directory of *current buffer*: `if [ -f Makefile ]; then make -C %:p:h $*; else make -C %:p:h/.. $*; fi`